# Why calling strcpy() leads to changes of my source string?

Tags: c, strcpy

```
main()
{
      char a[]="abss";
      char c[]="";
      strcpy(c,a);
      printf("%s",a);
}
```

Why does the source string `a` change on using `strcpy()` it is checked only when string `c` is greater than or equal to string `a`??

Comment: Because `c` is not long enough to hold 5 characters.  The way you defined it, it only has length 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`c` has size `1` but you try to copy 5 characters into it. This causes undefined behaviour.

To explain what you are seeing, probably what happens is that `c` and `a` are stored next to each other in memory, so the things you write into `c` overflow and land in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have enough storage for c (only a 1 byte terminator)  you are overwriting memory.

try char c[8]="";

Answer (score 1):

**Official answer:**

The memory allocated for the destination string is 1 character, and the length of the source string is 5 characters. So you are invoking undefined behavior by the C-language standard.

**Practical answer:**

The memory allocated for the destination string is 1 character, and the length of the source string is 5 characters. Your specific compiler has probably allocated the source string immediately after the destination string in memory. So the first character is successfully copied into the destination string, and the remaining 4 characters are copied into the source string itself.

---

Please note that you have yet another problem, as the destination string is no longer null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the destination which is unallocated. In your case it should be

```
char[8] c;
```

and it should work fine